# Problema al cerrar el scanner en un método statico

Tags: java, scanner

Dentro de una clase tengo un método para validar la introducción de números por teclado.

```
package FuncionesComunes;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class clsComunes {

    public static int leerEntero() {

        boolean error = true;
        int numero = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Introduzca numero: ");
            try {
                numero=sc.nextInt();
                error=false;

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR. debe introducir un numero");
                sc.next();                      
            }

        } while(error);

        //sc.close();
        return numero;      
    }
}
```

Al método lo llamo desde otra clase.

```
package ejercicios;
import FuncionesComunes.clsComunes;

public class ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero1, numero2;

        numero1 = clsComunes.leerEntero();
        numero2 = clsComunes.leerEntero();
    }
}
```

Si no cierro el scanner todo funciona correctamente. 
Sin embargo, cuando cierro el scanner aparece un error de "java.util.NoSuchElementException".
No le encuentro explicación...

¿Alguna ayuda?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si en el `catch` pones **`sc.nextInt();`** en vez de `sc.next();`?

Comment: Como esta creado tu método lo mejor es no llamar .close() ya que el problema es causado porque al llamar .close() se cierra también "System.in".

Comment: @A.Cedano en ese caso sucede lo mismo.

Las respuestas que me han dado indicando que se cierra también el System.in son correctas. ¡Os lo agradezco !

Answer (score 0):

La razon por la cual esta mandando un error es debido a que el Scanner esta ligado a un System.in, este es un objeto abierto por la maquina virtual de java (JVM), el cual cuando tu le ordenas al Scanner cerrarse, tambien cierra el System.in, la segunda vez que intentas crear un Scanner, debido a que solamente inicializas el Scanner (System.in sigue "nulo"), es cuando se encuentra con este error.

Lo que puedes hacer es dejar que la JVM sea quien se encargue de cerrar el Scanner simplemente quitando el Scanner.close(), el IDE te va a marcar una advertencia, puedes hacer 3 cosas:

1. Ignorar la advertencia
2. Agregar la anotacion de @SuppressWarnings("resource") antes del Scanner
3. Extraer el scanner a modo de que sea un objeto de tipo `private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` a nivel de la clase, de nuevo, sin cerrar el Scanner.

Referencias (en ingles): https://coderanch.com/wiki/678613/Don-close-Scanner-tied-System

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede cuando llamas el método [.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--) es que cierras el Scanner pero también el Input stream creado por `System.in`.

En este caso al volver a llamar el `Scanner` lo correcto sería no cerrarlo.

```
 numero1 = clsComunes.leerEntero();
 numero2 = clsComunes.leerEntero();
```